# Bright type of material for kitchen countertop

Tags: kitchens, stone, materials, countertops

I came across this image of a bright stone used for a kitchen countertop as shown in an [architecture blog post](https://www.ad-magazin.de/artikel/asket-grunder-august-bard-bringeus-in-stockholm).

[image: kitchen countertop]

[image: kitchen countertop 2]

I'm trying to find out what kind of stone this is, but I had no luck so far. In the article they describe this as marble, but I doubt that.

**Do you have a clue what it could be?**

Comment: It could be anything - artifical stone, marble, or laminate/veneer of some sort.  I am Voting to Close, as asking for opinions.  It is unlikely to be marble. Why not ask the blog poster ?

Comment: I don't rate it particularly "bright" as compared to most marble - that dull brown tone is brighter than black granite, but not very "bright" IMHO.

Comment: The actual material is unknown from a picture, but the material it may be, or may be "faking" in various other materials at various levels of faithfulness is pretty unabiguous and non-opinion based, @RohitGupta

Comment: Post a comment on the blog - ask them. Take the pics to your local custom cabinet/counter place and ask them. Oh, and to answer your only asked question, No, I don't have a clue what it is.

Comment: It's interesting to see how completely useless some comments on here can be, when a perfectly valid answer was already given long before

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's more likely a manmade conglomerate stone, or it could be a natural [Breccia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breccia).

[image: Breccia aurora]

A very similar if not the same look is described as Breccia Aurora. Which is a type of marble. *[Image Source](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.graniticompar.it%2Fimages%2Fcatalogo_prodotti%2Fmarmi_tecnici%2Fmarmi_tecnici_macroscaglia%2FAQ-Stone%2520BRECCIA_AURORA.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=10fb9b30b79ef6d3f8a43c5bbd6b0f45d3e484211941911a1f32c26542bc3919&ipo=images), no affiliation.*